# Ember rootURL with Hash

Tags: ember.js, salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying to embed an Ember application into Salesforce, specifically a VisualForce (VF) page. Salesforce uses the convention that your custom VF is available at:  `https://<instanace>.salesforce.com/apex/<myVFPage>`

Salesforce does NOT allow sub-folders.  For instance, if I try to reach the following URL, it will fail because it will attempt to resolve a VF page at the location of the sub-folder.  For instance, you cannot do this:

```
https://<instanace>.salesforce.com/apex/<myVFPage>/childPage
```

Previously, my workaround had been to use a hash.  Like this:

```
https://<instanace>.salesforce.com/apex/<myVFPage>#/sub-route
```

Unfortunatley I cannot get Ember to resolve this correctly.  It strips the hash from the rootURL and treats the above URL as resolving to `'/'` route instead of `'/sub-route'`

Is there a way I can set the Router.rootURL property to include the hash value.  I want to do this:

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  rootURL: config.baseURL
});
```

Where `config.baseURL = '/apex/myVFPage#/'`

Thoughts?  I recognize it's probably not standard to have the rootURL contain a hash.

Andrew

Comment: Have you considered using `App.Router.reopen({  location: 'hash' });` which  already separates server and client with "#"?

Comment: @jesenko, you're absolutely correct!  The default location is 'auto' and it was inteferring with the routing.  If I specify location: 'hash' it just works!  No rootURL is required. Thank you so much!!! I wish I had found you 5 hours ago. If you submit an official answer I'm happy to give you credit.

Comment: I am glad that helped :) I have just posted an official answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Router will already separate server and client part of URL with hash when Router's `location` is set to `hash`, i.e.

```
App.Router.reopen({ location: 'hash' });
```